# How to activate a Slider by pressing a button?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I have a Slider control, with 5 values. ValueChanged property: in the method I posted the various functions. How do I make sure that the ValueCahnged is activated only by pressing a button and not before?

```
private void InizioVeloceClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //Button
        {

        }

private void SliderDifficolta_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e) //Slider
        {
            if (e.NewValue==1)
            {

            }

            if(e.NewValue==2)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Does the slider have a ReadOnly property?

Comment: No, why? What would?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, you should "reverse your thinking". Instead of calling `ValueChanged` and doing something based on the slider value only when the button is pressed, the `Click` should read the slider value and do something based on that value.

```
private void InizioVeloceClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //Button
{
    switch(SliderDifficolta.Value)
    {
        case 1:
            // do something if 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            // do something if 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            // do something if 3;
            break;
        case 4:
            // do something if 4;
            break;
        case 5:
            // do something if 5;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: "the switch expression must be a bool, string, etc."

Comment: `<Slider Header=" Imposta difficoltà" Loaded="SliderDifficolta_Loaded" x:Name="SliderDifficolta"  TickFrequency="1" StepFrequency="1" TickPlacement="Inline" Minimum="1" Maximum="5" Margin="0,190,0,251" Background="#FFD4BB18" LargeChange="10" Value="3" Foreground="#FFF8610B" SmallChange="0" ValueChanged="SliderDifficolta_ValueChanged" />`

Comment: Do you have the whole thing? Not just the slider, but it's surrounding XAML? Post it in an edit on the original question, so that the formatting is somewhat preserved.